# Libgdx: checkerboard-like pattern

Tags: android, libgdx

Here is the basic, default code in libgdx, which just renders image on red background:

```
public class Test extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("img.png");
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.7f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        img.dispose();
    }
}
```

The image is just a small (100x100px) png filled with semi-transparent white (actually, the checkerboard appears also with completely opaque image).
But when I run this code on Android device here is what I get (magnified, screenshot taken with android studio, but it's noticeable on some real devices and emulators and when taken with power+volume down combination):
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK20u.png).
This appears also when I use Texture Atlas and different Texture Filters.
And everything is in png format, so it's not a lossy compression.

And my question is: why it appears?

Comment: Could be dithering. Set r, g, b, and a to 8 in the AndroidApplicationConfiguration.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks! It's a lot better now!